# Динамический placeholder для ImageView

Tags: android, xml, picasso, android-imageview

Есть элемент **ImageView** у которого высота и ширина имеют свойство **wrap_content**.

```
... 
           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/previewImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_ssmall"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/upsTextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleTextView"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />
...
```

Через **Picasso** подгружаю картинку по url. Обрезаю картинку по высоте, если изначальный размер был больше 600 пикселей.

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load(url)
   .resize(0, 600)
   .onlyScaleDown()
   .into(previewImageView)
```

В итоге подгружаемая картинка может быть любого размера в высоту и ширину, но не больше 600 пикселей в высоту. Каким образом можно подставить placeholder для картинки, если изначальный размер картинки неизвестен?

Проблема в том, что несколько изображений расположены в **recyclerView** и если подгружаемая картинка имеет ширину или высоту меньше, чем у placeholder, то размер самого **ViewHolder** меняется и если пользователь находится в середине списка, то после подзагрузки сверху картинки его либо перекинет наверх или вниз на несколько пикселей, что не очень приятно для глаза.

Comment: По вашему принципу работы никак. Надо фиксировать высоту элемента recyclerView, а картинки в нем уже подгонять под этот размер как нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу два варианта:

1. Хранить/получать высоту картинки там же, где и ссылку на картинку
2. Зафиксировать высоту элемента списка и обрезать картинку по одному из принципов:
      а) справа и слева отступы допускаются, сверху и снизу нет. Если w/h у картинки меньше w/h у ViewHolder, то картинка заполняет в высоту холдер, растягиваясь если высота картинки меньше высоты холдера. Если w/h картинки больше, то картинка заполняет холдер по ширине, обрезаясь слева и справа
      б) никаких отступов не допускается. Если w/h картинки меньше - обрезаем сверху и снизу, больше - слева и справа.

Вариант с разрешением отступов сверху и снизу не рассматриваю, т.к. это будет смотреться весьма стремно